# How do I use inserted values using getopts

Tags: bash, shell-script, getopts

I have this bash code combined with getopts and if I understood getopts correctly
OPTIND contains the index of the next command line option and all the command line options provided to shell script are presented in the variables $1, $2, $3 etc.. Correct me if I am wrong but basically the same concept as local variables in the functions.

So according to this why options  `[-a somevalue ]` or `[-b somevalue ]` won't give me any results. What am I doing wrong?

```
OPT_A=A
OPT_B=B

while getopts :a:b FLAG; do
 case $FLAG in
    a) 
      OPT_A=$OPTARG
      ;;
    b) 
     OPT_B=$OPTARG
      ;;
  esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))

    while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do

if [[ -z $OPT_A ]]; then
    if [ `echo $1 | grep -o '\.' | wc -l` -ne 3 ]; then
        echo "Parameter '$1' does not look like an IP Address (does not contain 3 dots).";
            exit 1;
        elif [ `echo $1 | tr '.' ' ' | wc -w` -ne 4 ]; then
            echo "Parameter '$1' does not look like an IP Address (does not contain 4 octets).";
        exit 1;
            else
        for OCTET in `echo $1 | tr '.' ' '`; do
                if ! [[ $OCTET =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                        echo "Parameter '$1' does not look like in IP Address (octet '$OCTET' is not numeric).";
                        exit 1;
                elif [[ $OCTET -lt 0 || $OCTET -gt 255 ]]; then
                        echo "Parameter '$1' does not look like in IP Address (octet '$OCTET' in not in range 0-255).";
                        exit 1;
                fi
        done
    fi
fi


if [[ -z $OPT_B ]]; then
        if [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [ "$2" -ge 1 -a "$2" -le 10000 ]; then 
            echo "chosen variable: $2";
            exit 1;
            else echo "variable $2 is not in range '1 - 10000'";
            exit 1;
        fi
    fi

    done
    exit 0
```

Comment: You put the `:` **after** the option letter to indicate that it takes an argument after it. So it should be `a:b:`, not `:a:b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because all of your logic depends on one of `$OPT_[AB]` being null. But even if you don't pass a `-[ab] $OPTARG` parameter, you're still setting them at the top of the script with `OPT_[AB]=[AB]`. So your logic chains never get past the root...

```
if [[ -z $OPT_A ]]; then...
```

...statement.

Well... not *all* of your logic depends on that. You're also doing:

```
shift $((OPTIND-1))

    while [ $# -ne 0 ]...
```

So if you passed `script -a arg` then `getopts` would set `$OPT_A` to `arg` and `$OPTIND` would come to 3. So you would `shift 2` *(all of your positionals)* then immediately fail the test in `while`. So your `case` would set `$OPT_A` and the next thing that happens is `exit 0`. So I guess you'd never even get to check for an empty `$OPT_A` anyway.

And even that would be ok since most of your logic is designed to test for failure - but your script *only* `exit`s. You probably do the `$OPT_A` var, but you don't do anything with it. You can't use that value after the script `exit`s - not without some preset IPC, but there's none of that here. The script is called in a subshell and the values it sets are lost when it returns to the parent shell.

What's more the optstring `:a:b` doesn't allow for an `$OPTARG` to `-b`. A leading colon in the optstring signifies quiet operation - it doesn't write to `stderr` if there's an issue with the options or their arguments. But a colon *trailing* an option char is what signifies that the option should expect an argument. Like:

```
while getopts :a:b: FLAG
```

...that would indicate two options that expect arguments. It can be tricky though because if you indicate that it is supposed to take an argument then if `getopts` finds it without one it flags it as an error:

```
sh -c 'getopts :a:b: opt -a; echo "$opt $OPTARG"'
```

...which prints...

```
: a
```

In that case the option winds up in `$OPTARG` and the `:` winds up in `$opt`. It is clearer if we're less `:`quiet about it:

```
sh -c 'getopts a:b: opt -a; echo "$opt $OPTARG"'
No arg for -a option
```

So, you need to check for `:` colon and for `?` - which is another type of error and which is conventionally rerouted to print some short `--help` sort of thing.

Personally, I would make sure `$OPT_[AB]` were both empty to start with, do some logic on setting them correctly, and, when through with the test loop, make my last test one for a null value. If they haven't any value at all then it must be for some reason I haven't handled, and it is an error regardless. Here's a start at how I would go about working that test loop...

```
param_err(){
    set '' "$@"
    : "${1:?Parameter '$OPTARG' does not look like an IP Address $2}"
}

test_oct(){ 
    oIFS=$IFS; unset "${IFS+o}oIFS"; IFS=.
    for oct in $1; do  [ $oct -lt 256 ] || 
        param_err "('$oct' too large)"
    done; unset IFS oct
    : "${oIFS+${IFS=$oIFS}}"
}

a_param()
    case ${1##*.*.*.*.*} in (a) OPT_A=A;;  #some default - no arg provided                                            
          (.*|*..*|*.) param_err '(empty octet)';;
          (*[!.0-9]*)  param_err '(octet is not positive integer)';;
          (*.*.*.*)    test_oct  "$1"; OPT_A=$1;;
          (*?*)        param_err '(too few octets)';;
          (*)          param_err ${1:+"(too many octets)"} '(null param)';;
    esac

unset OPT_A OPT_B
while getopts :a:b:c:d: opt
do    case ${opt#:}$OPTARG in
      a*)   a_param "$OPTARG";;
      b*)   b_param "$OPTARG";; #tests as needed similar to a_param()
      ?*)   help;;              #param_err should call this too, but it just exits
      esac
done
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21582/discussion-on-answer-by-mikeserv-how-do-i-use-inserted-values-using-getopts).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a shebang line at the top, so the shell you are using (`sh`, `dash`) is likely not to support `[[`. You should start the script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or any other location `bash` is in, in the unlikely case that is not the path to bash on your system (`type bash`).

Comment: i add as you said, but there is still no improvement..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:  while getopts :a:b FLAG; do

To This:            while getopts :a:b: FLAG; do